# Link one title to a different page other than its content of a view page

Tags: views, 8

I have a Drupal 8's views page in which Title and body of a specific content type is listed. I have enabled the title to link its content (node).

Supose if I have a list of 10 titles with its body listed, is there any way to override the link of one or two titles in order to redirect to a different page rather than its content/node.

Comment: Is it a field or an entity view?

Comment: This can be possible with global php in views ,use database select query load the specific node(say node id=12) ,then find its title,link it to custom url

Comment: @Vikramfz16 i think using global php in views is not a good idea as it has some security concerns

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this by using jquery. I attached a jquery in global library (To add jquery and css to drupal 8 [refer this page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme))

I needed a url redirection while clicking on the link /node/7 from the views field to /another-page. The jquery for which is as follows

```
$('.view-class a[href$="node/7"]').attr('href', '/another-page');
```

This selects the anchor tag with the 'view-class' and href attribute value ends with 'node/7' and redirects to '/another-page'